# If statement value checking not working

Tags: php, if-statement, geolocation, geo

I'm using ***GeoPlugin*** to check where my visitors come from. I am getting the ***CountryCode*** by using `$geo["geoplugin_countryCode"];`

I redirect people by doing a if check in PHP. I don't know why, but it always redirects me to the last link [***EN***] in the if statement. The code should send me to the [***NL***] site, because I am from The Netherlands. I am not using a vpn/proxy or something else.

```
if ($countryCode == 'NL') {
    header('Location: http://notworkingsite.com/GeoPlugin/NL/', TRUE, 302);
}
if ($countryCode == 'TR') {
    header('Location: http://notworkingsite.com/GeoPlugin/TR/', TRUE, 302);
}
if ($countryCode == 'DE') {
    header('Location: http://notworkingsite.com/GeoPlugin/DE/', TRUE, 302);
}
else {
    header('Location: http://notworkingsite.com/GeoPlugin/EN/', TRUE, 302);
}
```

FULL PAGE

```
<?php

$user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));
$countryCode = $geo["geoplugin_countryCode"];

if ($countryCode == 'NL') {
    header('Location: http://notworkingsite.com/GeoPlugin/NL/', TRUE, 302);
}
if ($countryCode == 'TR') {
    header('Location: http://notworkingsite.com/GeoPlugin/TR/', TRUE, 302);
}
if ($countryCode == 'DE') {
    header('Location: http://notworkingsite.com/GeoPlugin/DE/', TRUE, 302);
}
else {
    header('Location: http://notworkingsite.com/GeoPlugin/EN/', TRUE, 302);
}

?>
```

Comment: *$geo = unserialize(...* and you are sure, that the content is a serialized php array?

Comment: Yes, because without the if statements, when doing a echo on $countryCode it shows my CountryCode [NL] You can try the code by yourself doing an echo on the variable.

Comment: please post the output of *var_dump($geo);*